# Botão compartilhar do facebook exibindo informações erradas no "box_count"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, facebook

Em um projeto baseado em wordpress que eu estou trabalhando, eu tenho um modal que recebe dinamicamente várias informações provenientes de uma post-loop.

Este modal serve como uma espécie de "Preview" o post completo.

Dentro desse modal deve existir opções de compartilhamento (Facebook, + g, twitter, etc).

As URLs que serão utilizados pelos botões de compartilhamento são as urls do post completo. Para passar os valores dinamicamente eu uso JavaScript.

Até então, tudo funciona bem. O problema é que quando você compartilha o post, o contador do botão do facebook não aumenta. Para exibir o número atual de compartilhamento é necessário para fechar o modal e abri-lo novamente.

Eu acho que é necessário reabrir o modal devido ao uso de FB.XFBML.parse (); para atualizar a url.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de recarregar o botão para exibir as informações corretas sem fechar o modal? Como uma função de callback para recarregar o botão facebook quando o usuário compartilhar o conteúdo?

Parte do código html do modal:

```
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id))
           return;
           js = d.createElement(s);
           js.id = id;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
     </script>
     <fb:share-button id="fb_share_quick" href="#" layout="box_count" width="58"></fb:share-button>
```

Parte do código javascript que muda a url:

```
jQuery('.showPreview').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('fb\\:share-button').attr('href', 'http://google.com');
    FB.XFBML.parse();
});
```

Alguém pode me dar alguma dica sobre como eu posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei se entendi bem mas pelo que eu percebi queres mostrar botões de compartilhamento na frontpage para as devidas publicações/postagens é isso?!

utiliza isto em vez de carregares mais JS no teu site wordpress:

**HTML**

```
<a class="random-class-button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" width="38" height="38" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Lqo1eJjzHyE/UypQ90roR-I/AAAAAAAACyI/EOQYZGrz1qI/s1600/facebook-logo.png"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.random-class-button{
/* background:green; personaliza a class à tua maneira */
}
```